# iOS Facebook Authentication PhoneGap on TestFlight

Tags: ios, facebook, phonegap-build, testflight

I'm currently testing my app on my iPhone that I built using Phonegap's Adobe Build with Apple's TestFlight application. My app contains Facebook authentication and when I click the authentication button I am presented with the following error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or 
>       more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
>       It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must 
>       be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I did a bit of research online and I added the iOS Platform along with my Bundle ID in the respective field on facebook's developer panel but that did not appear to fix things.

Comment: Are you using the facebook javascript sdk? If you are then it wont work. Facebook Authentication only accepts connections from urls defined in the Website URL or Canvas URL. Since you are going through testflight, your iDevice's address is the url, so thats why you are getting that error. To fix it, you need the exact url that the iDevice is trying to connect to the facebooks servers through.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only have specific urls, not general ones that would accept connections from all the iDevices. I faced the same problem a while back and found the only solution was to use the Native iOS Facebook SDK, which kind of defeats the purpose of using phonegap.

Comment: @Minidodds I think that I may have found a solution that would require that I setup a local environment with Phonegap and then link to a Facebook-Phonegap SDK. I'll post the answer when I've figured it out.